# Find the ranking of an integer in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ranking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mysql rank function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333665/mysql-rank-function)

I have the following countryTable

```
country  clicks
-------  ------
0        222
66       34 
175      1000
45       650
```

How do I get the ranking of say country 45 which is 2 in this case?

Comment: I assume u want that in mysql? do notice mysql is to store data rather than to implement logic. Although, it can be done. But from my experience bottlenecks for the majority of apps is the DB rather than the business logic layer

Answer (score 2):

Ordered by `country ASC`:

```
SELECT 1+COUNT(*) AS ranking
FROM countryTable
WHERE country < 45 ;
```

Ordered by `clicks DESC`:

```
SELECT 1+COUNT(*) AS ranking
FROM countryTable AS t
  JOIN countryTable AS c
      ON c.clicks > t.clicks
WHERE t.country = 45 ;
```

Comment: Does not cover cases where there is a tie.

Comment: @SalmanA Why, I think it does. It doesn't cover only the case when there is no country `45`.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b8975/3: two countries have same clicks. The ranks are 1, 2, 2, 4 (better 1, 2, 3, 4 or 1, 2, 2, 3). OP did not mention if/how ties should be handled though.

Comment: @SalmanA I agree that ties may complicate things (depending how the OP wants to deal with them). My query simulates the `RANK()` function: [Ranking Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx). The 1, 2, 3, 4 would be `ROW_NUMBER()` and would require clarification for how ties should be handled. The 1, 2, 2, 3 would be `DENSE_RANK()` in standard SQL.

Comment: [SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/47a6a/2)

Comment: +1 for for simulating `rank()` :)

Answer (score 2):

You can get 2 rank as below it like below:

```
Select * from tabeName order by clicks limit 1,1
```

For 3 rank:

```
Select * from tabeName order by clicks limit 2,1
```

Comment: Hey, how come I give the same answer and get downvoted???? :-D damm...people are a herd, not you. your ansdwer is the best ;-) and i'll upvote u

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
  SELECT  @ranking:= @ranking + 1 rank,
          a.country,
          a.clicks
  FROM    tableName a, (SELECT @ranking := 0) b
  ORDER BY a.clicks DESC
) s
WHERE country = 45
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/51c7e3/3)

Comment: Does not cover cases where there is a tie. One extra variable will help.

Answer (score 1):

This will show the correct rank (2) for country 45. You don't specify how to rank ties, so you may want to change the comparison to suit you. Non existing countries rank as 0.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) rank 
FROM countryTable a
JOIN countryTable b
  ON a.clicks <= b.clicks
WHERE a.country = 45
```

[SQLfiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4fe22/2).

Comment: It works. But (somehow unrelated if you don't mind) how do I access the return value in php? I tried $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die(mysql_error()); echo $row['rank']; but it returns blank

Comment: @PutraKg Sounds like the correct approach, not sure what your problem may be. You may want to change to mysqli_* functions since mysql_* functions are deprecated, but both should work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

`X` is the rank you need to look for:

```
SELECT * FROM T ORDER BY clicks DESC LIMIT X-1,1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another (stunningly fast) way (albeit limited to 256 rows):

```sql
SELECT country
     , clicks
     , FIND_IN_SET(clicks,(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT clicks ORDER BY clicks DESC) FROM country_clicks)) rank
FROM country_clicks
```

or, if you prefer...

```sql
SELECT FIND_IN_SET(clicks,(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT clicks ORDER BY clicks DESC) FROM country_clicks)) rank
   FROM country_clicks
  WHERE country = 45;
```